# Sub-rows in a column that align with other rows in the table?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a table that looks like this:

```
A             | foo  | bla
 A.1          | bar  | bla
  A.1.a       | baz  | bla
   A.1.a. ... | quz  | bla
B             | bfoo | bla
 B.1          | bbar | bla
  B.1.a       | bbaz | bla
   B.1....    | bquz | bla
```

i.e, the same-depth "child" rows are horizontally aligned (e.g., A.1 and B.1 align), and each row is vertically aligned (e.g., A.1 aligns with "bar")

The only solution I can think of is by using `<td>` with left padding so that the content is moved over to the right (and programmatically generating the amount of padding). That feels like a hack, though. I was hoping for more of a pure-css/html solution, but can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: You want to create a table, so you have to use `<td>`. And you want internal margin on the left, so you use `padding-left` with different value given the depth of the number system : `.lvl1` = 5px left padding, `.lvl2` = 10px left padding, etc. I don't see what feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I would use single clases on each child to add a custom margin-left, while the rest of the elements should stay on the same position:

```css
td {
  min-width: 50px;
}

.level {
  display: table;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.child1 {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.child2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.child3 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level child1">A</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td class="level child2">A.1</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td class="level child3">A.1.a</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level child1">B</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td class="level child2">B.1</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td class="level child3">B.1.a</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="level child1">C</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td class="level child2">C.1</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td class="level child3">C.1.a</td>
        <td>| foo |</td>
        <td>| bla |</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The depth isn't limited to 3. It may be arbitrarily deep